# Laptop DVD drive not working in Ubuntu 14.04--nothing is mounting in the Devices section

Tags: mount, dvd

Ubuntu newbie here.

I'm trying to play a commercial DVD, but the drive doesn't appear to be recognized (the DVD spins for roughly 30 seconds before stopping entirely. I cannot see any additional devices mounted or find the media anywhere). I've seen several solutions to similar problems here and none of them have worked for me. Any ideas?

Results of `sudo lshw -C disk`:

```
*-disk                  
   description: ATA Disk
   product: ST9320325AS
   vendor: Seagate
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sda
   version: BSM1
   serial: S2WB3S7H
   size: 298GiB (320GB)
   capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
   configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=00055ea4
*-cdrom
   description: DVD-RAM writer
   product: CDDVDW SN-208BB
   vendor: TSSTcorp
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sr0
   version: AS01
   capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
   configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

I ran this with a DVD in the drive.

Comment: Please define *doesn't appear to be recognized*. Are you trying to play a commercial DVD? If so, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Comment: I am trying to play a commercial DVD, but when I insert the disk, it doesn't mount. The drive makes noise as though it were going to start playing or automount for about 30 seconds before stopping entirely.

Edit: Also, I followed the link and tried to install the software, but I already have the most recent version installed.  Thanks for sending it, though--hadn't considered that it might be an issue with a restricted format before.